# Throttling restful actions on a per user basis

Tags: python, bottle

What is the best approach to throttling the number of actions a user can do to one per minute?

```
@route('/do_something/<cmd>',method=['GET','POST'])
def my_command(cmd):
    # Only allow this to be executed once every 60s per user/ip.
```

I am looking for a server side solution, as I want to enforce this based on the users IP-address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be already existing `throttling` solutions in python and more specifically bottle framework.
You may roll out your own using a storage, and some minor scripting.
Since,your throttling period is pretty small i.e. 1 minute, memcache would be a good candidate to store the values.

1. Generate a hash  based on conditions required to throttle. eg  hash(user+ip) etc.
2. When you receive new request, check memcache for values existing with hash as key.

3
(a). Value does not exist :
 - Store current timestamp integer in memcache with this hash as key, TTL 1 minute.

(b) Value exists :
 - Discard the request.

Here is a very good decorator written for redis ( for flask framework, but will work anywhere else too ) :

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/70/

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like a reasonable solution. I was hopping for a bottle framework, but having slept about 2 hours last night I couldn't come up with any when searching Google. I'll see if I can find one, otherwise I'll probably use a simple memory database to cache these as you suggested.

Comment: The flask snippet was exactly what I needed. Thanks again @DhruvPathak.